How to Display Progress Bars with Scrolling in Python's rich Library?
I'm using Python's rich library to display progress bars in my terminal application. However, I'm encountering an issue where the progress bars get truncated with ... when the number of tasks exceeds the height of my terminal.

Here’s a simplified version of my code:
from rich.progress import Progress
from time import sleep

with Progress() as progress:
    tasks = [progress.add_task(f"Task {i}", total=100) for i in range(50)]
    while not progress.finished:
        for task in tasks:
            progress.update(task, advance=1)
            sleep(0.1)

The terminal height is not sufficient to display all tasks, and rich shows ... at the bottom to indicate truncation.
Is it possible to make the progress bars scrollable, so that the user can see all tasks by scrolling up and down in the terminal?

It is not reasonable to display too much progress at the same time.
Generally, asyncio.Semaphore(max_concurrent) is used to limit asynchronous threads.
For example:
async def download_async():
    semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(max_concurrent)
    tasks = []

    async def bounded_action(task):
        async with semaphore:
            return await action_async(task)

    with progress:
        for id in id_list:
            rand = random.randrange(10, 30) * 10
            task_id = progress.add_task("", id=id, start=False, visible=False)
            task = AsyncTask(task_id=task_id, total=rand)
            tasks.append(bounded_action(task))

        results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
        for result in results:
            if isinstance(result, Exception):
                progress.console.print(f"FAILED: {result}")

